docker-compose container not reachable by external network - port is 'filtered'
I've be shooed over from SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79256455/docker-compose-container-not-reachable-by-external-network)
I have an application running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS where I can't configure the port (fixed to 8455) and I need to run it multiple times.
Therefore I have set up a docker container to be accessible by port 8457.
But I can't connect to the container from external.
version: '3'
services:

    t32tcpusb_3-6:
        image: ubuntu
        command: /home/fileuser/t32/bin/pc_linux64/t32tcpusb
        privileged: true
        stop_grace_period: 2s

        volumes:
          - "/home/fileuser/t32:/home/fileuser/t32"
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6:/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        devices:
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        ports:
          - "8457:8455"


Connecting from localhost:8457 is working.
SSH-Tunnel to localhost:8457 is working.
Connecting via Host-IP:8457 fails as timeout.

If I run the application outside of the container with its native port, it works, port shown as 'open':
$ sudo nmap -sS -p8455 192.168.1.104
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8455/tcp open   unknown

If I run the application inside of the docker, it won't work from external, port shown as 'filtered'
$ sudo nmap -sS -p8457 192.168.1.104
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8457/tcp filtered unknown

The docker-proxy is also running fine:
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                   NAMES
42ad878db020   strace_t32tcpusb_3-6   "strace /home/fileus…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours   8457/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8457->8455/tcp, [::]:8457->8455/tcp   t32tcpusb_3-6_strace
$ ps aux|grep docker-proxy
root        9293  0.0  0.0 1745360 3668 ?        Sl   22:37   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8457 -container-ip 172.22.0.2 -container-port 8455
root        9300  0.0  0.0 1745360 3700 ?        Sl   22:37   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8457 -container-ip 172.22.0.2 -container-port 8455

Do you have any idea what is causing the docker-related ports to be filtered?
What is also confusing: This setup was working fine several months, and just now I discovered it failing..
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.22.0.2           tcp dpt:8455

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Dec  6 21:01:24 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:708]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:708]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [451:95724]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [451:95724]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.22.0.0/16 ! -o br-d3567e42c5bf -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.0/16 ! -o br-f458dffe8f92 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 ! -o br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.22.0.2/32 -d 172.22.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8455 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i br-d3567e42c5bf -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-f458dffe8f92 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d3567e42c5bf -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8457 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.22.0.2:8455
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Dec  6 21:01:24 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Dec  6 21:01:24 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4111:1250700]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3484:515980]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o br-d3567e42c5bf -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-d3567e42c5bf -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-d3567e42c5bf ! -o br-d3567e42c5bf -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-d3567e42c5bf -o br-d3567e42c5bf -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-f458dffe8f92 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-f458dffe8f92 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-f458dffe8f92 ! -o br-f458dffe8f92 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-f458dffe8f92 -o br-f458dffe8f92 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 ! -o br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -o br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.22.0.2/32 ! -i br-d3567e42c5bf -o br-d3567e42c5bf -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8455 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-d3567e42c5bf ! -o br-d3567e42c5bf -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 ! -o br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-f458dffe8f92 ! -o br-f458dffe8f92 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-d3567e42c5bf -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-7f8ffa0ea2d9 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-f458dffe8f92 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Dec  6 21:01:24 2024
$ sudo nft list ruleset
sudo: nft: command not found


$ ifconfig
[...]
br-953f115bed7a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:82ff:fee4:adc2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:82:e4:ad:c2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 592 (592.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64  bytes 7477 (7.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fd66:cc77:8f51::3a6  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd66:cc77:8f51:0:feaa:14ff:fe0d:9f92  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::feaa:14ff:fe0d:9f92  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fc:aa:14:0d:9f:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 449909  bytes 321962064 (321.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 298968  bytes 132522597 (132.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3757  bytes 13852600 (13.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3757  bytes 13852600 (13.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


$ telnet localhost 8457
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

^]
telnet> close
Connection closed.

$ telnet 192.168.1.104 8457
Trying 192.168.1.104...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

$ sudo docker inspect t32tcpusb_3-6_strace|grep Address
[...]
$ telnet 172.22.0.2 8455
Trying 172.22.0.2...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

^]
telnet> close
Connection closed.



filtered indicates a firewall issue. Possibly outside of your server.

The server (x86_64) and the computer i use for nmap (rPI) are both behind a NAT (simple router with OpenWRT), so whatever dumb stuff we try out there does not affect the rest of the network.
So, for this experiment it is just: rPI (nmap) > server (docker) without further layers in-between. **Is there any other (default) firewall is should be aware of? Already posted ufw and ipdates output.. **

Well, if no packets return (which is meant by filtered) in 99% of the cases it's a firewall. The other options are incorrect routing (0.9%) and actually hanging processes that have a socket open but just don't answer (0.1%).

What strikes me as odd is that according to the ps aux output both containers have the identical internal IP address. This should not be the case.

Please post iptables-save and nft list ruleset output instead (of iptables -L). Note that (AFAIK) docker-proxy matters only when the DNAT rule is not there (TBH, I don't even have any idea when that would "normally" happen.) Also, by "from external" are you referring to access from/by a host within the same LAN?

@Gerald: There is just one container running, I understood that one docker-proxy takes care of ipv4 and another of ipv6. (?!)
@Tom: I updated my post to include iptables-save and docker ps. nft is not installed.
Yes, all devices are in same LAN. Internal = Localhost, External = Same LAN.

I am not spotting anything wrong with the iptables rules (but you could check whether iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT helps, in case something quirky is going on.) Btw, you mentioned that Connecting via Host-IP:8457 fails as timeout, but do you mean like that would fail even if you are connecting from the host itself (using Host-IP instead of localhost)? And what if you connect via container-ip from the host itself? (Make sure you obtain container-ip right before the attempt, and with port 8455 instead in that case, of course.)

This is all weird. I appended the outputs of ifconfig and telenet (as probe) to the last box. Only connecting via localhost works. Host-IP and Docker-IP even fail differently. Calling FORWARD_ACCPET before didn't change anything.

even fail differently Well because as I said, you should use 8455 when you use 172.22.0.2.

Oh. It got late yesterday. Yes, Docker-IP:8455 is working
